# How to use auto layout for a label in interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

How would I go about setting constraints for my price label to stay on the side of the screen? Below Is a picture of what I want my tableviews to look like on all iPhones.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df0vv.jpg

Comment: And whats the problem? Yours look fine for me, the blue label just need to pin on the right side?

Comment: @Tj3n I need to set the constraints for the blue label to fit into all size phone screens. I can't figure out what constraints I need to add to the label.

Comment: @Ryan Aschermann, follow my answer step.

Comment: @aircraft have been following the steps closely but still can't seem to figure out why the label is not showing up on the 5c display.

Comment: @RyanAschermann which label? and the constaints did you set corretly?

Comment: @aircraft The blue label on the right side is not showing and yes I followed your directions step by step.

Comment: @RyanAschermann and if you left label is okay, must be somewhere you lost do in right label,them are similar.please see 4)  I have ignore the right label's step 2)!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to do:

1)first add left label

[image: first add left label]

2)ctrl + drag the left label to `cell` content, and choose `Center Vertically in Container`:

[image: choose <code>Center Vertically in Container</code>]

3)Click `Add New Constraints in the right bottom of interface builder`,
deselect the `Constraint to margins`, and click the left dotted line and set the left margin value , `eg:8`

[image: Add New Constraints]

4) As the same to left label, you can set constraints to your right label, and the different is only you should set right margin nor left margin , in there I omit the `Vertically in Container` step of right label, you can see 2):

[image: set right margin]

**EDIT**
as matt's advice, you better set the right label's `alignment` to `right`;

[image: set right label alignment]

Comment: The price label isn't showing up on the iPhone 5 display, why would this be?   http://imgur.com/a/uKji4

Answer (score 0):

The blue label is on the right and needs to stay on the right. It is sized automatically by its content. So just pin its right edge to the right of its superview and its top or bottom (not both) to the top or bottom of its superview.